# Read value from XML ignoring any namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have an XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
   <section name="publisher" type="KP.Common.Util.XamlConfigurationSection, KP.Common"/>
</configSections>

<publisher>
   <p:Publisher xmlns:p="http://schemas.KP.com/xaml/common/notification">
   <p:KPLogSubscriber MinimumImportance="Information" />
   <p:EventLogSubscriber MinimumImportance="Warning" Source="KPTTY" Log="Application" />
   <p:DatabaseMailSubscriber xmlns="http://schemas.KP.com/xaml/data/ef" MinimumImportance="Error" ProfileName = "" Recipients = "administrator@firm.com" Subject = "KPTTY Error" />
</p:Publisher>
</publisher>
</configuration>
```

I am trying to read the value of the key Recipients using this code:

```
XmlDocument config = new XmlDocument();
config.Load(configPath);
XmlNode node = config.SelectSingleNode(@"/*[local-name() = 'configuration']/*[local-name() = 'publisher']/*[local-name() = 'Publisher']/*[local-name() = 'DatabaseMailSubscriber']/@Recipients");
Console.WriteLine(node.Value);
```

but I get an exception (node is null). Is there something wrong with my Xpath? I am trying to ignore any namespaces that might not be present in the xml.

Answer (score 1):

If it is OK to use Linq2Xml

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(fname);
var recipients =  xDoc.Descendants()
                    .First(d => d.Name.LocalName == "DatabaseMailSubscriber")
                    .Attribute("Recipients")
                    .Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to do `local-name` for "Recipients". "Recipients" attribute have empty prefix meaning its namespace is `xmlns="http://schemas.KP.com/xaml/data/ef"` as defined on the "DatabaseMailSubscriber" element.

I.e. if you don't care of path you can simple use "//" for "any child:

```
"//*[local-name() = 'DatabaseMailSubscriber']/@*[local-name() = 'Recipients]"
```

Note: consider actually using namespace properly... or use `XDocument` as suggested by L.B.